# testing that a json can be rendered as a highchart

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, highcharts

I want to make a site that makes highcharts. However, on the backend, I want to confirm that the json I am getting back is a valid highchart. I would like to do this with some kind of decorator, eg,

```
@app.route('/this_is_a_chart')
@chart
def make_chart():
  return jsonify({
    # some generated chart data
  })
```

then it would catch that this should be a highchart, and test that it is valid. How is this possible in flask?

Comment: And what does highcharts require of a JSON value then? The decorator is possible, sure, but without objective criteria, there isn't anything we can answer here.

Answer (score 0):

The decorator would look like this, but you need to tell us how to validate the json and how exactly you want to handle the error. This decorator throws an exception.

```
def chart( func ):
    def r():
        json = func()
        if not_valid_json( json ):
            raise "NotAHighChart"
        return json
    return r
```

Comment: therein lies the problem; is there a confirmed way in which to check if json is valid highcharts easily, or would it be a matter of hacking away at it?

Comment: Show me an example and I might come up with one; I doubt that there is a library or something to do it.